# Jquery ajax fileupload is not working in IE9 standard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, file-upload

Fileupload working everywhere like chrome, IE10, etc. But when My QA tested in IE9 it fails. Action controller get Request.Files are coming '0' length files.

Is something wrong with IE9 or my code is wrong?

```
function initSimpleFileUpload() {
            console.log("initSimpleFileUpload");              
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                url: '../admin/image/uploadfiles',
                dataType: 'json',
                acceptFileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png|svg\+xml)$/,
                add: function(e, data) {
                    jqXHRData = data;
                },
                done: function(event, data) {

                },
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    // console.log(data);
                    // console.log(data.url);
                    if (data.message == "false") {
                        //alert("filename already exists");
                        $("#oops_dialog").html("@Html.Raw(i18n_Models_Image.ImageFileExists)");
                        $("#oops_dialog").dialog("open");
                    }
                    else if (data.message == 'checksumExists') {
                        $("#oops_dialog").html("@Html.Raw(i18n_Models_Image.ImageCheckSumSame)");
                        $("#oops_dialog").dialog("open");
                    }
                    else if (data.message == 'fileTagNotExists') {
                        $("#oops_dialog").html("@Html.Raw(i18n_Models_Image.ImageTagTextBox)");
                        $("#oops_dialog").dialog("open");
                    }
                    else if (data.message == 'unexpectedError') {
                        $("#oops_dialog").html("@Html.Raw(i18n_Models_Image.ImageUploadUnexpectedError)");
                        $("#oops_dialog").dialog("open");
                    }
                    else if (data.message == 'fileTagSame') {
                        $("#oops_dialog").html("@Html.Raw(i18n_Models_Image.ImageSameFileTagNotAllowed)");
                        $("#oops_dialog").dialog("open");
                    }
                    else if (data.message == "success") {
                        window.location = data.url;
                    }
                },
                fail: function(event, data) {
                    if (data.files[0].error) {
                        alert('@i18n_Models_Image.UploadCancelled');
                    }
                }
            }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function(e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            });
        }


$('#fileupload').on('change', function(e) {
                if ($('#fileupload').length > 0) {
                    $('#lnkUploadSubmit').attr('disabled', false);
                    $('#divFileName').show();
                    $('.progress').show();
                } else {
                    $('#lnkUploadSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $('#divFileName').hide();
                    $('.progress').hide();
                };
            });
            $('#fileupload').on('click', function(e) {
                console.log("click");
                $('#lnkUploadSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#divFileName').hide();
                $('#inputFileName').val('');

            });
```

### controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("Admin/Image/UploadFiles")]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            var files = Request.Files;
            //checking file types and file max size
            var errMsg = CheckFileTypesAndMaxSize(files);
            if (errMsg != "success")
            {
                Error(errMsg);
                return Json(new { message = "error", url = Url.Action("Index", "Image") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I guess something is wrong with IE 9. You need to submit the form to upload the file to server.
You can have a method in controller which will be called on page submit and this method will have a parameter something like this... HttpPostedFileBase file